# can someone fix my PS1 for bash

Tags: bash, prompt, escape-characters

I seem to have too many colour escapes so it only works in some prompts - can someone please correct for me ?

```
PS1='\[\e[0:35m[\u@\e[0:33m\h\e[m \e[0:35m\w]\e[m \e[0:33m`git branch 2> /dev/null | grep -e ^* | sed -E  s/^\\\\\*\ \(.+\)$/\(\\\\\1\)\ /`\e[m\] \n$ '
```

Comment: Please don't crosspost http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245885/can-someone-fix-my-ps1-for-bash

Answer (score 4):

Replace all colons with semi-colons. Colons are not meaningful in escape sequences for colors.